# Gtk 3.24 - slide button in GtkSharp

Tags: c#, gtk3, gtk#

I am using GtkSharp C# bindings for Gtk 3.24 and I am new to Gtk world. What I need to make is a special kind of button shown in the image below. The button is activated by moving the green part to the right. If the movement ends before reaching the right edge, the slider returns back to the left. The widget is operated via a touch panel.

[image]

I tried to customize `Gtk.Switch` widget which is closest to my requirements via CSS, but here I did not manage to get rid of its Click event which allows to toggle the button by a single mouse/finger click. Also I don't like the switching threshold is exactly at 50 % of the widget.

Another possibility could be customizing the `Gtk.Scale` widget or maybe creating the widget from scratch?

Please could you recommend me some easy way of implementing such button?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I took inspiration from this [article](http://www.kcjengr.com/programing/2017/10/16/dragable-gtk-widgets.html). The approach is very simple:

- The custom component is derived from `Gtk.Fixed` container which allows absolute positioning of its elements.
- The static part of the slider (background) is `Gtk.Image` placed at the top-left corner.
- The slider is `Gtk.Button` component with custom image inside.
- The component listens to the `ButtonPressEvent` ands stores the initial touch position. The `ButtonReleaseEvent` is used to evaluate where the button movement finished and finally the `MotionNotifyEvent` handles the slider position changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would address this by creating a custom Switch-derived widget, overriding the OnDrawn () method and implementing my own widget rendering which responds to whether the switch is in an on or off position. Switch is probably the closest widget in terms of behaviours that you would want; it's just the rendering is different. Something like this:

```
public class MySliderSwitch : Gtk.Switch
{

  ...

  protected override bool OnDrawn (Cairo.Context context)
  {
    // draw your widget using the given Cairo Context.
    // this is just an example drawing a rectangle.
    context.LineWidth = 2.0F;
    context.Rectangle (0, 0, AllocatedWidth, AllocatedHeight);
    context.SetSourceRgb (0, 0, 0);
    context.StrokePreserve ();
    context.SetSourceRgb (1, 0, 0);
    context.Fill ();

    return true;
  }

  ...

}
```